# Féminins de « malin » et « bénin »

Tags: genre, étymologie

Les féminins de « malin » et « bénin » sont respectivement « maligne » et « bénigne ». Alors que j'ai des centaines d'exemples de mots se terminant en -IN et se féminisant simplement par l'ajout d'un E final, il semble que ces deux mots soient les seuls dont on remplace -IN par -IGNE. Ma question est donc : pourquoi ces deux exceptions ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parce que ces adjectifs étaient originellement épicènes et se terminaient en -igne (issu directement des adjectifs latins équivalents en -ignus). Le masculin est une dérivation régressive ([en:back-formation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back-formation)) à partir de ces formes, d'où l'irrégularité.

On rencontre parfois *maline* à l'oral, et même à l'écrit. (*Le Bon Usage, 14e éd.*, §545)